# How-To Azure: configure 2 VM from different accounts to work in one virtual network?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network, azure-sql-database

We signed up to BizSpark and have different Azure accounts. Our idea is to set up 2 VM  on different accounts: first for backend and other for database, but for security reasons we need to make them work in one VPN.

Is it possible to do so or maybe there's any workaround?

I'm not much familiar with that so really don't know how to do it better.

P.S. Ideas about using same subscription for holding both VMs (or using 1 VM instead of 2) isn't applicable, 'cause we need rather much resources, so we cannot allow this.

Comment: You can use point to site connection. See [the article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-point-to-site-create/)

Comment: @JackZeng there's one problem with classic portal: it cannot display non-classic VMs which I use. But thanks for link: I'll try to find similar in new portal.

Comment: first of al : if you're short of resources you can always open a ticket with MSFT in order to increase the number of resources on a subscription (check this for some giuidance : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-subscription-service-limits/ ) 
second : you can create VNET 2 VNET conenctiosn , and these works subscription unaware: please see all subtopics under the getting started topic of Azure VPN gateways https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-plan-design/ ther eyou can find articles on VNET 2 VNET